# How do I convert the MemoryStream from a Google Drive Get request to an XML File C#?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working in .Net Core 2 and I am using the google drive v3 API and fetching an XML file.  I get back a MemoryStream but am unable to read the MemoryStream to an XmlDocument.  I have tried a couple files and the size of the memory stream matches the file size so I am confident I am acutally getting the data.  How do I turn that MemoryStream into an XmlDocument?  Or string that I can parse to XML?

I have tried loading the stream to an xml document and a text reader.   The text reader comes back with an empty string and the xml loader says parent node not found.

```
//Fetch the file from Google Drive
var request = _driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
request.Download(stream);

//How I Try and parse to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

//How I try to load to xml
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(stream);
```

Comment: Have you tried rewinding the `MemoryStream` before calling `ReadToEnd` on it?

Comment: That was it!  You should totally submit that as an answer so I can mark it as the awesomeness it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `XmlDocument`, it sounds like what you're getting back may not be valid XML without a little massaging, so you should start with the `MemoryStream`-based implementation to see what you're getting from the service.

To get *that* working, you need to "rewind" the stream. Streams have a concept of "current position", like a cursor, and methods like `Download` traditionally leave the cursor at the end of the data after loading it into the stream. Sometimes this doesn't matter, like when you're using a `FileStream` to write the data directly to a file, but if you're loading the data into a `MemoryStream` and then want to immediately read it, you need to first reset the cursor back to the beginning of the stream with `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.